# 2D array diagonals sum

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to sum primary diagonal and secondary diagonal of 2D array of python like this:

```py
records = [[12, 5, 2 , 1], [15, 6,10 , 1], [10, 8, 12,1], [10, 8, 12,1]]


primary_diagonal_sum = 0 
array_size =  len(records)
secondry_diagonal_sum = 0 

for index , record in enumerate(records):
    primary_diagonal_sum += records[index][index]
    array_size =  array_size - 1
    secondry_diagonal_sum += records[index][array_size]
```

and it's working fine. Just want to know if this is this written well ? is this efficient or maybe  it can improve working wise ?

Comment: Efficient at what scale? Have you learned Numpy?

Comment: @Reinderien doing  this as program solving and algorithm. So don't want to use any library .

Comment: If you "don't want to use any library", this will never, ever be efficient at scale

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to attempt to solve this with your own algorithm whole-cloth while still having reasonable performance, switch to a better language

Comment: Alternatively, if you are just wanting to learn Python, this is fine.

Comment: @Reinderien thanks for recommendation . Currently working on python for project my seniors always says my program need to be efficient so trying to learn good ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PEP-8

The [Style Guide for Python Code](https://pep8.org/) has several recommendations which you have deviated from in your code:

### White space

Commas should be followed by 1 space, and should not be preceded by any spaces:

Change:

```
records = [[12, 5, 2 , 1], [15, 6,10 , 1], [10, 8, 12,1], [10, 8, 12,1]]

for index , record in enumerate(records):
```

to:

```
records = [[12, 5, 2, 1], [15, 6, 10, 1], [10, 8, 12, 1], [10, 8, 12, 1]]

for index, record in enumerate(records):
```

### Unused variables

If a variable is not used, but is needed for syntactic reasons, the `_` throwaway variable should be used:

Change:

```
for index , record in enumerate(records):
```

to:

```
for index, _ in enumerate(records):
```

### Group similar statements

If several statements are similar, if possible, keep them together:

Change:

```
primary_diagonal_sum = 0 
array_size =  len(records)
secondry_diagonal_sum = 0 

for index , record in enumerate(records):
    primary_diagonal_sum += records[index][index]
    array_size =  array_size - 1
    secondry_diagonal_sum += records[index][array_size]
```

to:

```
array_size = len(records)
primary_diagonal_sum = 0 
secondry_diagonal_sum = 0 

for index, _ in enumerate(records):
    array_size = array_size - 1
    primary_diagonal_sum += records[index][index]
    secondry_diagonal_sum += records[index][array_size]
```

### Assignment operators

You’re using `+=` operator; why not `-=` also?

Change:

```
    array_size =  array_size - 1
```

to:

```
    array_size -= 1
```

## Confusing code

`array_size` should be the size of the array.  The reader would expect this to always hold.  But in this code, it appears the size of the array is decreasing???:

```
array_size = len(records)

for index, _ in enumerate(records):
    array_size =  array_size - 1
    secondry_diagonal_sum += records[index][array_size]
```

Pick a better variable name for `array_size`, or calculate the index:

```
array_size = len(records)

for index, _ in enumerate(records):
    secondry_diagonal_sum += records[index][array_size - 1 - index]
```

or simply use negative indexing:

```
for index, _ in enumerate(records):
    secondry_diagonal_sum += records[index][-1 - index]
```

## Enumerate

The elephant in the room:

```
for index , record in enumerate(records):
    # code not using `record`
```

Why are you using `enumerate(…)` if you are not using the `record` portion?

```
for index in range(len(records)):
    …
```

Or, actually use the `record` field:

```
for index, record in enumerate(records):
    primary_diagonal_sum += record[index]
    secondry_diagonal_sum += record[-1 - index]
```

## sum

Python has a builtin function for summing `sum()`, often used with a generator expression.  You can even use `reversed(…)` to traverse `records` from the bottom up, eliminating the need for negative indexing:

```
primary_diagonal_sum = sum(row[idx] for idx, row in enumerate(records))
secondry_diagonal_sum = sum(row[idx] for idx, row in enumerate(reversed(records)))
```